# How can I pass dynamic content inside rails attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
Class Foo
field :title
end

Class Bar
 field :description
end
```

In IRB I tried:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > f = Foo.new(title: "<%= bar.description %>")
 => #<Foo _id: 506b2de61d41c84b07000002, _type: nil, title: "<%= bar.description %>"> 
1.9.3p125 :002 > f.save
 => true
1.9.3p125 :004 > f.title
=> "<%= bar.description %>"
```

How I put `Object Bar` inside `f.title` attribute?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the string interpolation, just set the title to bar.description

```
f = Foo.new(title: bar.description)
```

If you wanted to include extra stuff with it you can do this.

```
f = Foo.new(title: "Title for: #{bar.description}")
```

If you really wanted the erb handlers in there you could do

```
f = Foo.new(title: "<%= #{bar.description} %>")
```

Answer (score 1):

That kind of string interpolation works on `.erb` templates, but not on simple ruby objects.
If you still want to use interpolation then you can do:

```
f = Foo.new(title: "#{bar.description}")
```